# How can I add images to an Angular gallery array?

Tags: arrays, angular, gallery

I have a small project built in Angular and I wanted to create a gallery to it.

I made a gallery component and followed the instructions on a website (https://murhafsousli.github.io/ngx-gallery/#/lightbox) on how I could make the gallery. I wrote the code according to the tutorial but now I'm stuck on how I could add images into the array. I have the images in the assets folder but I don't know how to link them to the code. This is my current code:

Gallery component HTML

```
    <div class="grid-item"
          *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index"
          [lightbox]="i">
          <img [src]="item.data.thumbnail">
        </div>
Gallery component.ts

    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Gallery, GalleryItem } from '@ngx-gallery/core';
import { Url } from 'url';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-gallery',
  styleUrls: ['./gallery.component.css'],
  template: `
    <div class="grid">
      <div
        class="grid-item"
        *ngFor="let item of space$ | async; let i = index"
        [lightbox]="i"
        [gallery]="galleryId"
      >
        <img [src]="item.data.thumbnail" />
      </div>
    </div>
  `
})
export class GalleryComponent implements OnInit {
  galleryId = 'myLightbox';
  items: GalleryItem[];

  constructor(public gallery: Gallery) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // Load items into gallery
    const galleryRef = this.gallery.ref(this.galleryId);
    galleryRef.load(this.items);
  }
}
```

How could I add images to that array for the gallery to work?

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't seem to be updated. You have two html templates in this code. One is iterating over space$ and the other is iterating over items. Which one is right?

Comment: what does you this.items looks like ?

Comment: I followed the code on the website I'm not sure which code should I use or how it should look like.